# Can published excel be modified from with in sharepoint?

Tags: excel

I have an excel table that i wish to publish which displays our users call stats on a certain date. Change the date cell and the table refreshes through a series of IF statements from the data tab. Can I make excel do this from the browser with out the users having to open it in excel? I can publish excel but it is always non editable . thanks for any advice.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are referring to a spreadsheet that has been published using Excel Services, then I believe the answer is no - you cannot edit spreadsheets using this functionality.

You can however use Excel Web Apps to edit cells within the browser, assuming that you have Office Web Apps installed within your server farm.

A good place to start on Excel Services vs. Excel Web apps is [here.](http://blogs.technet.com/b/tothesharepoint/archive/2010/07/21/excel-services-and-excel-web-apps-common-different-features.aspx)

I hope that helps.

Ben